# Spacing in front of citation (natbib, super)

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib, superscripts

I am using `\usepackage[super]{natbib}` for my citations. When using that, the horizontal spacing in front of and after the citation are different. How do I increase the spacing in front of that citation, such that it is even?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\begin{document}
foo~\cite{bibitem} bar.

\medskip

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{bibitem} 
        Somewebsite,
        \\\texttt{http://www.thisissomerandomwebsite.com}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natbib discards the space when using the `\cite` command in `super` mode. Two possible solutions are to use `\citenum`, that does not discard spaces, and superscript that, or to define an open brace consisting of a space. The advantage of the first approach is that you can still use `\cite` to get a superscript close to the word (which is a bit more standard typographically speaking). The disadvantage is that you need to define a new command for combining `\citenum` and superscript. For the other approach this is reversed: you can use the `\cite` command but you cannot have a superscript close to the word anymore (unless you insert negative spacing manually).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}
% first approach
\newcommand{\citespace}[1]{%
\textsuperscript{\citenum{#1}}%
}
% second approach
\setcitestyle{open={\ }}
\begin{document}
foo\citespace{bibitem} bar. foo\cite{bibitem} bar.

\medskip

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{bibitem} 
        Somewebsite,
        \\\texttt{http://www.thisissomerandomwebsite.com}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]